# Is there a way to make Django-registration-redux work with `@login_required`?

Tags: python, django

I use Django-registration-redux in my project so I don't have to bother with all the login details. However, now I created a view with the `login_required` decorator and encountered a problem. The problem is that when the user is not logged in, then the decorator works by redirecting

```
/events/create_event/
```

to

```
/accounts/login/?next=/events/create_event/
```

Which is nice, but the particular URL is not in the `registration-redux` URLs, so the whole thing falls apart. Is there an elegant way to make `django-registration-redux` work with the `@login_required` decorator?

Answer (score 1):

Login page

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'login_view' %}?next=requst.META.HTTP_REFERER">
   {{form.as_p}}
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
....
"django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
   ......
   try:
      return redirect(request.GET['next'])
   except:
      return redirect('/')
```

Comment: So what you are saying is I should just bypass the django-registration-redux?

Comment: Also, shouldnt the template context processors be set as TEMPLATES=[{'OPTIONS': {'context_processors': [list_of_processors]}}] ???

Comment: if you are using django.contrib.auth.views.login as view for login, then no need to make any changes to the view, it will work perfectly.

Comment: And another thing: Shouldn't the `urls.py` file be changed as well?

Comment: I am using `django-registration-redux` which defines its own views and urls. My question is not how to make the redirections work, but how to make them work with `django-registration-redux`.

Comment: Did you passed next keyword in login form action?

Comment: Yes, but the error I get is that the page cannot be found.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my problem. The login page does not even open. The Login page template does not even get processed. This is because, as I said, the `@login_required` decorator makes a redirect to the webpage `/accounts/login/?next=/events/create_event/`, and there is nothing in the URLconf that helps Django figure out what this does. I assume this is because the `django-registration-redux` simply imports the auth views without the correct regexes.

Comment: I discovered where the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing the file `registration\auth_urls.py`

to add

```
url(r'^login/(?P<next>\?next=(.*))', auth_views.login, {'template_name':'registration/login.html'}, name='auth_login_redirect'),
```

and now, everything is working like it should.